# Why is $G$ abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

> If $|G|=pq^2$ with $p,q$ primes and if $p<q$, with $q\not\equiv\pm1\mod p$, why is $G$ abelian ?

The $3^{rd}$ Sylow theorem implies that $n_p|q^2$ and  $n_p\equiv 1 \mod p$,

By hypothesis, $n_p$ should be $1$, thus the $p$-Sylow subgroup is unique and therfore normal by $2^{nd}$ Sylow theorem.

If we consider $q$-sylow subgroups, say one of them is $Q$, then it is normal (because its index is the smallest prime factor of $G$ etc, I know this).

How do I continue?

Comment: I don't think that's a proper use of wlog.  The fact that $p$ and $q$ can be distinguished by the power they appear means that we cannot just relabel if $p>q$.  The condition on $q \mod p$ does force $p<q$, but wlog isn't generally used in that context.  It would be for if you knew that the proof in the $|G|=p^2q$ case was entirely analagous to the $|G|=pq^2$ case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If two subgroups of a group are normal, have trivial intersection, and generate the group via elements of the form $xy$ with $x$ in the first group and $y$ in the second, then the group is the direct product of the two groups. The group of order $q^2$, is abelian, so the result follows.

Comment: why is the intersection only the identity element ?

Comment: The order of the intersection divides the order of both groups. Only 1 satisfies that condition.